# grunt-contrib-sass doesn't work in Windows

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I am trying to compile scss file to css using Grunt, but I fail for unknown reason.

Here is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: 'dependencies',
                    cleanup: true,
                    layout: 'byComponent'
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            foundation: {
                files: {
                    'a.css': 'a.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('dependencies', ['bower:install']);
    grunt.registerTask('assets', ['sass:foundation']);
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
> grunt assets
Running "sass:foundation" (sass) task
Warning: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C\MySQL\bin ENOENT Use --force to continue

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you post a screenshot of the error rather than copy/pasting the error?

Answer (score 2):

i resolved the issue, installing "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1" (that's a old version, but it's works for me)

```
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1"
}
```